# Is this true that $N_G(H) \subseteq N_G(H \cap K)$ if not what is the counter-example?

Tags: group-theory

Is this true that $N_G(H) \subseteq N_G(H \cap K)$ if not what is the counter-example? I am confused in this question?

Clearly $g \in N_G(H)$ then $g(H \cap K)g^{-1}\subseteq H$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not true.  Consider the 2-Sylow subgroup $V\trianglelefteq A_4$.  Let $G=A_4$, $H=V$ and let $K$ be any 2 element subgroup of $V$.  Then $N_G(H)=G$ since $V\trianglelefteq G$, but $N_G(H\cap K)=N_G(K)=V$, which is smaller.  ($G/V$ permutes those three 2 element subgroups cyclically.)